# PHP zip->open returns error code 5 (Read Error)

Tags: php, zip

We had a site running, that uses the php zip functionality. Everyhthing worked fine for month - now we moved to a new server and the script doesn't work!

$zip->open() returns error Code 5 what is a read error.

I found out, that it has to do with the size of the zip files, as they are about 60mb. Smaller sizes about 30mb are working.

What could be the reason for that? I didn't find any configuration possiblility about the size of zip files!

Thanks,
Manu

Answer (score 1):

Does the zip file contain a lot of files, if so you might have hit a bug described here: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=40873

Comment: I have the same issue but the problem was in the .zip file name. It can't contain dots. `mytable.backup.zip` won't work but `mytable-backup.zip` will. Just in case someone runs into this same issue.